# Как создать работающее фононове приложение в Android Wear

Tags: java, android, android-wear

Добрый день.  Есть необходимость создать приложение для смарт часов под android wear. Специализированный аналог медиа плеера.

Приложение написано.. все запускается, но работает ровно 25 секунд, пока не гаснет экран часов.

Варианты типа:

1. вынос модуля проигрывания в отдельный сервис:

   ```
   startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
   ```
2. Создание в сервисе отделенного потока:

   ```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                      play();
                  }
          }).start();
          return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
   }
   ```

так же работают до отключения экрана.
   **Подскажите как запустить сервис в android wear, чтобы ни Ambient Mode и какие другие режимы отключения экрана его не прерывали. Или на худой конец не давать часам отключаться, пока приложение работает.**